# Not able to initiate AndroidDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selendroid

The code is :

```
WebDriver driver;

driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Error I am getting is :

> The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class
>   files

How can I fix this issue? My selenium and appium java client jars are already added in build path->Libraries

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are invoking the android driver incorrectly. Please use the following code to initiate an Android driver.

```
AppiumDriver driver;
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

You will be needing Selenium server, appium java client jar file in your classpath.

Comment: Tried all that. Still does not compile. Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The type org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Comment: Can you please post all of your class including the imports

Comment: The docs don't mention this but selenium-remote-driver needs to be included in the pom (dependencies) to get rid of this compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using the older version of Selenium standalone server jar. Import the latest "selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2" to your build path. This would fix your issue.